# Standard Bluetooth SIG Characteristic decoding

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am looking for documentation or examples on the data structure of the defined/default Bluetooth characteristics (https://btprodspecificationrefs.blob.core.windows.net/assigned-values/16-bit%20UUID%20Numbers%20Document.pdf).

I found (https://github.com/sputnikdev/bluetooth-gatt-parser/tree/master/src/main/resources/gatt/characteristic) which shows a lot of them but not all.

Is there perhaps another open source app with more of these available or even an official document that I can reference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is official documentation on this called [GATT Specification Supplement 6](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/gatt-specification-supplement-6/)